# Is there any document for the Python win32com operations on Powerpoint?

Tags: python, document, powerpoint, win32com

I have gat some samples about how to open a presentation and access the slides and shapes. But I want to do some more other operations(e.g. generate a thumbnail from a specified slide). What methods can I use? Is there any document illustrating all the functionalities?

Answer (score 9):

Not to discourage you, but my experience using COM from Python is that you won't find many examples.

I would be shocked (but happy to see) if anybody posted a big tutorial or reference using PowerPoint in Python.  Probably the best you'll find, which you've probably already found, is [this article](http://www.s-anand.net/blog/automating-powerpoint-with-python/)

However, if you follow along through that article and some of the other Python+COM code around, you start to see the patterns of how VB and C# code converts to Python code using the same interfaces.

Once you understand that, your best source of information is probably the [PowerPoint API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743835.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the samples Jeremiah pointed to, it looks like you'd start there then do something like this, assuming you wanted to export slide #42:

```
Slide = Presentation.Slides(42)
Slide.Export FileName, "PNG", 1024, 768
```

Substitute the full path\filename.ext to the file you want to export to for Filename; string.
Use PNG, JPG, GIF, WMF, EMF, TIF (not always a good idea from PowerPoint), etc;  string
The next two numbers are the width and height (in pixels) at which to export the image; VBLong (signed 32-bit (4-byte) numbers ranging in value from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647)

I've petted pythons but never coded in them; this is my best guess as to syntax.  Shouldn't be too much of a stretch to fix any errors.