# Python: Insert linked image into PowerPoint slide

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I'm trying to do is simple, insert a linked image into PowerPoint instead of doing a basic image insert for the purpose of saving my storage. I've tried [python-pptx](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html?highlight=add_picture#pptx.shapes.shapetree.SlideShapes.add_picture) but it does not have the feature that I want. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After make some further research, I found [win32com.client](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) which gives me the ability to control PowerPoint via [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) API.

Here's an example:

```
import win32com.client

ImagePath = r"D:\image.jpg"
Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
Presentation = Application.Presentations.Add()
Base = Presentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)
Base.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName=ImagePath, LinkToFile=True, SaveWithDocument=False, Left=0, Top=0, Width=200, Height=200)
```

Also, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708265/is-there-any-document-for-the-python-win32com-operations-on-powerpoint) for the [PowerPoint API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/powerpoint/object-model), it is for VB script but the implementation is almost the same.